# exclude an element from a grouping

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking for duplicates in a dictionary of type `Dictionary<long, MyClass>` using `MyClass.some_property` as the comparison value:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<long, MyClass>(...);
var duplicates = from d in dict
                 group d by d.Value.some_property into g
                 where g.Count() > 1
                 select g;
```

Now I need to exclude the first element in each grouping in the `duplicates` enumerable. How is this done without converting everything to another data structure? I want to avoid using any additional memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx)

```
var dict = new Dictionary<long, MyClass>(...);
var duplicates = from d in dict
                 group d by d.Value.some_property into g
                 where g.Count() > 1
                 select new {Key= g.Key, Values = g.Skip(1)};
```